# Wordpress JSON API get posts from a given date

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am using the plugin wordpress' RESTful API plugin called [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/json-api) and I would like to get posts from a given date. I tried many parameters but it didn't work for me, can you help me please?

Here is what I have tested for instance :

http://www.example.com/?json=get_date_posts&date=20140806&posts_per_page=-1

or

http://www.example.com/?json=get_posts&after=20140806&posts_per_page=-1

Comment: What didn't work? maybe `posts_per_page` -1 ? Or date like `2014-15-08`

Comment: The API is returning all posts from the creation of my website to 20140806 (using 2014-08-06 didn't change anything). In fact it is like the parameter `after` behave exactly like before

Answer (score 1):

This WP plugin has documentation [JSON API Docs](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/).

Please see this part [Method:get_posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#Method:-get_posts) this call accepts the same parameters as WordPress's WP_Query parameters, which can be found here [WP_Query parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

The part you are looking for is [Date parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).

Example: http://www.example.com/?json=get_date_posts&year=2012&monthnum=12&day=12&posts_per_page=-1

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I had already seen and tried that but it doesn't answer my need. Your solution gives the post of one date. What I want to do is get all posts from a given day to today. For example I want to specify a start date for example 20140803, and to have all the posts from the start day to today

Comment: I see, maybe try a combination of after and before where before is always today's date

Comment: Thanx it doesn't work neither. I don't know if I am using it well http://www.example.com/?json=get_posts&after=20140806 is correct right?

Comment: hmmm try switching get_posts with get_date_posts

Answer (score 0):

don't if it still helps but you should use something like this:
json=get_date_posts&date=after%2020150318

Answer (score 0):

You can get all posts from a date using get_posts with params below

count = -1

date_query[0][after] = 20160101

http://www.example.com/api/get_posts/?count=-1&date_query%5B0%5D%5Bafter%5D=20160101

You can see all date params on https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters